# Media queries are not adapting the layout in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I have used the media queries for different width.I have used 3 Style sheets for mobile, tab and desktop views as follows:-
For Mobile View:-

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 120px) and (max-width : 640px) { }
```

For Tab View:-

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 640px)and (max-width : 980px){  }
```

For Desktop View:-

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 980px) { }
```

When I am re sizing my browser then it is showing the adaptive view but while checking in mobile device the web page is still showing the browser view.

The responsive view is also not adaptive while checking in the Device Emulator functionality of the google chrome browser.

However the side menu bar used for mobile  view is still visible in the mobile view as expected but the remaining site is not adapting the width and height accordingly.

Can anyone explain the issue and reason behind it.

P.S. : I am restricted to media queries not able to use Bootstrap or any other framework for  making my site responsive.

Comment: Check your CSS within media query for mobile devices. As you said side menu bar works fine, so it's sure that mobile browser is surely getting the media query break point.

Comment: It would be better if you create a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net), for us to solve your issue.

Comment: which device widths are problematic, some examples would be useful, and have you set the `width=device-width` in your HTML `<meta>` tags? A jsfiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go. As per your media queries, browser is not sure what layout should be adapted because you have defined the same width as break point.
What you need to do is define media queries like this.

For Mobile View:-

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 120px) and (max-width : 639px) { }
```

For Tab View:-

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 640px)and (max-width : 979px){  }
```

For Desktop View:-

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 980px) { }
```

Hope this help you.! Do come back if still having issue.!

Comment: Sorry but I am still not getting the required adaption for mobile layout.

Comment: No issue.! Best way to this for mobile  layout is @media only screen and (min-width : 120px) and (max-width : 400px) { }. Then update the break point for others as well .! Further follow this link to get the more details on Media Queries. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: no still not achieved the desired result.I am checking the samething in chrome browser device emulator.this is not able to showcase the perfect view.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to remove `only screen and` and leave it like `@media (min-width : ...`
   these attributes is not required.
2. If it works but you really want to use `screen and` just remove the `only` keyword. From [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

> The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older
>   user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with
>   ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

3. If at least something from @media section is working for your mobile device make sure that ALL your @media sections placed at the bottom of your CSS file and that this file are linked to you html the latest among all other CSS files. If it still doesn't work for you as expected check your actual CSS code or make a demo for us. How to make [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

PS.: You don't have to specify `min-width` for the smallest screen in the list of `@media`

Comment: I have checked the code once again, but this layout is working fine when re sizing with browser.In case of mobile the web media query is being dominated over the mobile CSS.That is why the problem is occurring.

Comment: @Cheslab **only** and **screen** do have a defined purpose,  you can't just leave them out and expect the code will do what OP wants. They aren't causing the problem

Comment: @Mousey by minimize the code you can get closer to a solution of the problem. I don't expect OP will leave it how it is after the main problem would be solved. This question was asked yesterday and we still don't have a demo. Looks like there would be no answer. About `only`: desktop browsers have autoupdates even if you're running Win XP, which may be why they can handle it as expected, and what about OP's mobile device - I don't know, it can be from ancient era

Comment: OP only posted 3 lines, scroll down to @CodeRomeos answer

Comment: That's it, these 3 lines don't allow us to help OP with this problem. @CodeRomeos answer didn't help either. It looks for me like OP has a typo in his code or a pretty simple mistake, that's why I asked for a demo